# ffmpeg error : can you help me?

Tags: ffmpeg

Summary of the bug: Hello, I've created a network with the mininet simulator on ubuntu 14.04lts. In this network, I want to transfer video between two hosts. I used vlc in Sender host and I used ffmpeg in Receiver host. When I run the ffmpeg, I get a lot of these errors:

```
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3497, current: 3480; changing to 3498. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3498, current: 3481; changing to 3499. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3499, current: 3482; changing to 3500. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3500, current: 3483; changing to 3501. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[avi @ 0x66c1900] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:1; previous: 3501, current: 3484; changing to 3502. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

Here is the command used:

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/test1.sdp -acodec copy -vcodec copy /home/sana/lab/mrp/test1.avi
```

I searched on the internet and found http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git&a=search&h=refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster&st=commit&s=Non-monotonous+DTS+

Is this my question solution? How can I use it?

Comment: Since you aren't re-encoding, you can try this `ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/test1.sdp -fflags +genpts -i rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/test1.sdp -map 0:v -map 1:a -acodec copy -vcodec copy /home/sana/lab/mrp/test1.avi`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still get the errors. (but the number of errors is less than before)

Comment: And now also I'm getting alot of another error :                                                        **[rtsp @ 0x3d22b20] max delay reached. need to consume packet**
   **[rtsp @ 0x3d22b20] RTP: missed 12 packets**

Comment: Can you re-encode the audio?

Comment: Unfortunately I am a beginner.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i rtsp://10.0.0.1:8554/test1.sdp -af aresample=async=1,asetpts=N/SR/TB -vcodec copy /home/sana/lab/mrp/test1.avi`

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The number of errors was greatly reduced. But the amount of time it takes to get the entire video increases while I'm going to get video and audio in real time.